# java error: mainthread waits until second thread is executed

Tags: java, multithreading

I've made my own kind of statusbar. With a statusbareditor I can set some message on the bar and it disappears after 10 sec. Because my GUI may not be blocked, this statusbareditor works on a second thread. This works fine. But after editing the statusbar I set a new panel on the form. This new panel only appears after 10 secs. This is strange because the statusbareditor works on a different thread.

```
public void HandleLoggedIn(Person account) {
    StatusbarEditor reportThread = new StatusbarEditor(labelStatusbar, "Aangemeld als " 
            + account.toString() + ".");
    reportThread.start();
    asideform = new Asideform();
    asideform.AddFollower(this);
    this.add(asideform, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
```

and the statusbareditor-class:

```
public class StatusbarEditor extends Thread{

    private JLabel statusbar;
    private String text;

    public StatusbarEditor(JLabel statusbarlabel, String report){
        statusbar = statusbarlabel;
        text = report;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        statusbar.setText(text);
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StatusbarEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(statusbar.getText().equals(text)){
            statusbar.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only imagine what goes wrong there:

```
asideform = new Asideform();
asideform.AddFollower(this);
this.add(asideform, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Is this part updating your UI? If yes, you must take in consideration that your thread has most likely not come as far as you need it. Processing time is distributed approximately random as long as nothing else is defined.

**EDIT**

One more Thing:

```
 private JLabel statusbar;
```

Doesn't this belong to your UI class?

Comment: when I first open the asideform, and then start the thread, everything works as it should. But I think it's strange that the execution of "asideform = new Asideform()..." waits untill the thread is finished, and it should not.

Comment: did you check this with your Debugger? I bet it does not just "wait"

Comment: thanks. Indeed, when I don't pass the label as parameter, the execution works fine, execept the statusbar isn't changed. Now I start the thread after changing the panel and it works fine.

Comment: great that it works now! i guess you can mark this question as answered now :)

Answer (score 0):

without seeing "AsideForm" class it's hard to say but my guess is this is a race condition.
perhaps you need to prepare your asideForm object before starting the thread so the events will take place in the expected order.